# Build an Array of StringBuffer with x elements from a List of n elements

Tags: java

I have an initial list that contains: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 I want to create an array of StringBuffer that contains only 3 items per element as StringBuffer(String):

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7
```

Initially I resolved this problem as in the following example, but I don't want to use another list to do that:

```
List accounts = new ArrayList();
List<Person> listOfObjects = results.getResults();
for(Person p: listOfObjects) {
   String persAccount = p.getAccount();
   accounts.add(persAccount);
}
String s = listToString(accounts);

public String listToString(List list) {
 StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        b.append(String.valueOf(list.get(i)));
        if (i < list.size()-1)
            b.append(',').toString();
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

I think that an efficent way will be to create a StringBuffer and append all values in the for block.(3 by 3).

How can I do it in an efficient way?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Code Review. This code does not do what your description says it should do. I don't see an Array of `StringBuffer[]` and I don't see anything that makes the output happen in batches of 3 items.... Am I missing something?

Comment: I said that because I want to create an array that contains elements as Strings(each account will be appended to a StringBuffer in order to create a String of 3 items). I didn't mentioned that part because I think that will be a little bit different.

Comment: Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684640/build-an-array-of-stringbuffer-with-x-elements-from-a-list-of-n-elements

Answer (score 2):

## StringBuffer

The first thing that comes to mind is the fact that you're using a `StringBuffer` instead of a `StringBuilder`. A `StringBuffer` is synchronized which means it has the additional overhead that comes with it. Unless you are doing this in a multithreaded environment that affects this piece of code, switching to a `StringBuilder` will be a good improvement.

## ToString

Inside your loop you do `b.append(',').toString()`. Since you never do anything with the `String` that it returns, you are essentially needlessly creating a `String` each time it is hit.

## Strongly typed collections

You have the collection `accounts` defined as `List accounts = new ArrayList();`: there is no type specified.

Proper handling would be `List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();` so you're working with `Person` objects instead of general `Objects`.

---

This is aside from any remarks on whether or not your code fits your problem description, as @rolfl states. I don't see where you split it in sublists of 3 elements.